# An open and closed set? [Analysis]

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have the following question:
for which real numbers a and b is the set $[a,b] \bigcap \mathbb{Q} $ simultaneously open and closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

I do understand the classic example about the rational numbers being neither closed nor open in $\mathbb{R}$ ,but this hasn´t helped me thus far. I have the feeling I need to chose real numbers for a/b but i am still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a$ is rational and $b\ge a$. Can $[a,b]\cap\mathbb Q$ be open? Remember if $\epsilon>0$ there exists a rational $q\in(a-\epsilon,a)$. What does that tell you? The case where $b$ is rational is handled similarly.

Now assume $a$ and $b$ are both irrational. If $a\ge b$ then $[a,b]\cap\mathbb Q$ is empty, so in particular is both open and closed. What about if $a<b$? If $q\in[a,b]\cap\mathbb Q$, then $a<q<b$, so there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $(q-\epsilon,q+\epsilon)\subset(a,b)$. What does this imply? Moreover, if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $[a,b]\cap\mathbb Q$ convering to $x\in\mathbb Q$, what do you know about $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Iff $a>b$ or $a,b$ are both irrational.

If $a>b$ then $Q\cap [a,b]=\phi$ , which is open and closed in $Q$.

For any $c\in Q$ we have $c\in Cl_Q(Q\cap (c,c+1)$ and $c\in Cl_Q(Q\cap (c-1,c).$

For $a\leq b:$

If $b\in Q$ then $b\in Cl_Q(Q\cap (b,b+1),$ so $[a,b]\cap Q$ is not open in $Q.$ Similarly if $a\in Q$ then $a\in Cl_Q(Q\cap (a-1,a)$ so $[a,b]\cap Q $ is not open in $Q.$

If a and b are irrational then $[a,b]\cap Q= (a,b)\cap Q.$ By definition of the subspace topology,  $(a,b)\cap Q$ is open in $Q.$..... And $Cl_Q( [a,b]\cap Q)=Q\cap Cl_R([a,b]\cap Q)=Q\cap [a,b].$